# Java - Hadoop MapReduce reduce not executing

Tags: java, mapreduce

I am putting a `List<String>` to my Reduce function.

The data in the `List<String>` looks like

```
"banana:1"
"apple:3"
"carrot:2"
"ballon:1"
"cake:4"
"banana:14"
"apple:3"
"carrot:22"
"ballon:11"
"cake:9"
"banana:7"
"apple:6"
"carrot:5"
"ballon:3"
"cake:2"
```

I want my `Reduce` to get the maximum # `String.split(":")[0]` for every fifth element and collect the associated word. So, the associated words would be `cake, carrot, banana` since they are the highest scores for every fifth element. With that, `cake, carrot, and banana` will each get a +1. I want to iterate through my entire `List` to see how many +1's each word has.

I am currently getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` error in my `Reducer` and I am not sure why.

This is my Reduce:

```
Text mainKeyword = new Text();

@Override
public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> outputCollector, Reporter reporter)
        throws IOException {

    List<String> copies = new ArrayList<String>();
    String keyword = key.toString().split(":")[0];
    Integer score = Integer.parseInt(key.toString().split(":")[1]);


    int total = 0;
    while (values.hasNext()) {
        String keywordAndValue = key.toString();
        total += values.next().get();
        copies.add(keywordAndValue);
    }


    int maxIndex = 1;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < copies.size() + 1; i++) {
        if (Integer.parseInt(copies.get(i - 1).split(":")[1]) > Integer.parseInt(copies.get(maxIndex - 1).split(":")[1])) {
            maxIndex = i;
        }
        if (i % 4 == 0) {
            mainKeyword.set(new Text(copies.get(maxIndex - 1).split(":")[0]));
            count += 1;
            maxIndex = i + 1;
        }

    }

    outputCollector.collect(new Text(score.toString()), new IntWritable(count));
}
```

The exception comes with `if (Integer.parseInt(copies.get(i - 1).split(":")[1]) > Integer.parseInt(copies.get(maxIndex - 1).split(":")[1]))` but my each line is as described: `"word:#`" so the split should theoretically work.

Comment: 'but my each line is as described: "word:#" so the split should theoretically work.' ->  don't think so as it is  key.toString() for every i as of "keywordAndValue = key.toString();"

Comment: @kai I don’t understand what you’re saying.

Comment: "String keywordAndValue = key.toString();  copies.add(keywordAndValue);" you are storing the key( the part before the colon- most probably) multiple times in your "copy" list....

Comment: @kai The keys are “word:value” - where is it being stored twice?

Comment: @kai I am confused with your comment. Can you clarify?